# Intercept Request and add Parameters in WKWebView

Tags: objective-c, wkwebview

I tried to intercept a request and add request parameters based on the following code

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction decisionHandler:(void (^)(WKNavigationActionPolicy))decisionHandler {
NSURL * actionURL = navigationAction.request.URL;
if ([actionURL.host isEqualToString:kMyHost]) {
    NSString * headerField = @"Authorization";
    NSString * headerValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@", accessToken];
    if ([[navigationAction.request valueForHTTPHeaderField:headerField] isEqualToString:headerValue]) {
        decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicyAllow);
    } else {
        NSMutableURLRequest * newRequest = [navigationAction.request mutableCopy];
        [newRequest setValue:headerValue forHTTPHeaderField:headerField];
        NSMutableString *params = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithData:[newRequest HTTPBody] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        [params appendFormat:@"is_app_web_view=1&utm_source=ios"];
        [newRequest setHTTPBody:[[self encodeToPercentEscapeString:params] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicyCancel);
        [webView loadRequest:newRequest];
    }
} else {
    decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicyAllow);
}
}
```

I found that setting only http header works but once i add following lines of code, the request is not sent:

```
        NSMutableString *params = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithData:[newRequest HTTPBody] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        [params appendFormat:@"is_app_web_view=1&utm_source=ios"];
        [newRequest setHTTPBody:[[self encodeToPercentEscapeString:params] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Is this the proper way of adding the parameters? Can someone point me to the right direction regarding this?

Comment: as you are appending the data to the message body, it should be a POST request. Could you check the content-type of a body?...(like application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data or application/json). and post the error here to get more insights.

Comment: Yes. It is a post request. Content-type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded. I read in the documentation that  setting HTTPBody clears the input stream. Does that mean, all existing post parameters will clear out??? What should i do if i want to append more parameters to post request?